# Create a Dependent Drop Down Based on Link from Previous Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

How can I pre-select a drop down option depending on the link from another page?
Depending on which link the user clicks, I need to pre-select the appropriate drop down index on the resulting page.

First Page:

```
<a href="http://somesite.com?mySelect=1">Option 1</a>
<a href="http://somesite.com?mySelect=2">Option 2</a>
<a href="http://somesite.com?mySelect=3">Option 3</a>
<a href="http://somesite.com?mySelect=4">Option 4</a>
```

Second Page Code:

```
<select id="mySelect" name="mySelect">
    <option>Select Option</option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
    <option>Option 4</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript (Second Page):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("mySelect").selectedIndex="**Appropriate Index**";
</script>
```

I cannot figure a way to pass the above JS into a URL parameter. The above code only works when it is located on the same page as the drop down.
I need to add to the above JS in order to select and display the correct index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a different solution:

```
if (/REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_TEXT/.test(window.location.href)) {
document.getElementById("image").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("text3").style.display = "block";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use HTML5 local storage for save some params by click on link, and then take them on another page. 
article for example:
http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html